# Crystal Reports Export to .csv comma delimited string inserting blank columns

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a issue and need some expert help!  I'm trying to export a .csv field directly from crystal reports and I keep getting blank columns in between my datasets.  The report is one formula only in the details section, that contains a string separated by comma's like below.  Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

*Side note the requirements are an export directly to .csv so no export to data only then save to .csv will work.

[image: Crystal Reports Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach implicitly converts numbers to text. This might results in extra commas due to thousand separators.

Instead, use explicit conversion such as

```
ToText({your number}, 2, "")
```

to avoid the extra commas.

Comment: Perfect this sorted my issue, thank for you help and time, greatly appreciated!